# Reproducibility with multithreading and multiprocessing in Python (how to fix random seed)

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing, random-seed, reproducible-research

My code does the following:

- Starts processes to collect data
- Starts processes to test model
- One thread takes care of training (read data from collect processes)
- One thread takes care of testing (read data from test processes)
- Every time the training thread does a step, it waits for the testing to also do one step
- Before doing a step, the testing thread waits for a training step

I need to have reproducible results, but there is randomness in both the processes and the threads. I naively fix the seeds in each process and thread, but results are always different.

Is it possible to have reproducible results? I know threads are non-deterministic, but I don't launch multiple threads from the same pool: I have 2 pools, each launching only 1 thread.

Below is a simple MWE. I need the output to be always the same every time I run this program.

**EDIT**

Using the `initializer` argument in all pools I can have deterministic behavior *within* threads and processes. However, the order in which processes write the data is random due to multiprocesses non-deterministic behavior. Sometimes one process reads the queue first and writes, sometimes it's another process.

How can I fix it?

```py
import logging
import traceback
import torch
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor
from torch import multiprocessing as mp

shandle = logging.StreamHandler()
log = logging.getLogger('rl')
log.propagate = False
log.addHandler(shandle)
log.setLevel(logging.INFO)


def fix_seed(seed):
    torch.manual_seed(seed)
    torch.cuda.manual_seed(seed)
    torch.cuda.manual_seed_all(seed)
    torch.manual_seed(seed)
    torch.backends.cudnn.benchmark = False
    torch.backends.cudnn.deterministic = True


def collect(id, queue, data):
    #log.info('Collect %i started ...', id)
    while True:
        idx = queue.get()
        if idx is None:
            break
        data[idx] = torch.rand(1)
        log.info(f'Collector {id} got idx {idx} and sampled {data[idx]}')
        queue.task_done()
    #log.info('Collect %i completed', id)


def test(id, queue, data):
    #log.info('Test %i started ...', id)
    while True:
        idx = queue.get()
        if idx is None:
            break
        data[idx] = torch.rand(1)
        log.info(f'Tester {id} got idx {idx} and sampled {data[idx]}')
        queue.task_done()
    #log.info('Test %i completed', id)


def run():
    steps = 0
    num_collect_procs = 3
    num_test_procs = 2
    max_steps = 10

    data_collect = torch.zeros(num_collect_procs).share_memory_()
    data_test = torch.zeros(num_test_procs).share_memory_()

    ctx = mp.get_context('spawn')
    manager = mp.Manager()
    collect_queue = manager.JoinableQueue()
    test_queue = manager.JoinableQueue()
    train_test_queue = manager.JoinableQueue()

    collect_pool = ProcessPoolExecutor(
        num_collect_procs,
        mp_context=ctx,
        initializer=fix_seed,
        initargs=(1,)
    )
    test_pool = ProcessPoolExecutor(
        num_test_procs,
        mp_context=ctx,
        initializer=fix_seed,
        initargs=(1,)
    )

    for i in range(num_collect_procs):
        future = collect_pool.submit(collect, i, collect_queue, data_collect)

    for i in range(num_test_procs):
        future = test_pool.submit(test, i, test_queue, data_test)

    def run_train():
        nonlocal steps
        #log.info('Training thread started ...')
        while steps < max_steps:
            train_test_queue.put(True)
            train_test_queue.join()
            for idx in range(num_collect_procs):
                collect_queue.put(idx)
            log.info('Training, %i %f', steps, data_collect.sum() + torch.rand(1))
            collect_queue.join()
            steps += 1
        #log.info('Training ended')
        for i in range(num_collect_procs):
            collect_queue.put(None)
        train_test_queue.put(None)

    def run_test():
        nonlocal steps
        #log.info('Testing thread started ...')
        while steps < max_steps:
            status = train_test_queue.get()
            if status is None:
                break
            for idx in range(num_test_procs):
                test_queue.put(idx)
            log.info('Testing, %i %f', steps, data_test.sum() + torch.rand(1))
            test_queue.join()
            train_test_queue.task_done()
        #log.info('Testing ended')
        for i in range(num_test_procs):
            test_queue.put(None)

    training_thread = ThreadPoolExecutor(1, initializer=fix_seed, initargs=(1,))
    testing_thread = ThreadPoolExecutor(1, initializer=fix_seed, initargs=(1,))
    training_thread.submit(run_train)
    testing_thread.submit(run_test)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    run()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not familiar with `torch` and I could not easily tell whether its random number generator is sharable across all processes or whether each process has its own generator that will generate the same sequence of numbers if they are both seeded identically.

Let's first assume the generator is sharable, i.e. each process is effectively making calls to the same, sharable random number generator seeded with 0, and that the first two random numbers generated for such a sequence are 9 and 11. Let's assume you have only two `collect` processes, `p1` and `p2`. When you run the program the first time, this is the order of events:

1. p1 retrieves `idx` value of 0 from queue
2. p1 gets the first random number, 9, and assigns `data[0] = 9`
3. p2 retrieves `idx` value of 1 from queue
4. p2 gets the second random number, 11, and stores `data[1] = 11`

The next time you run, this is the order that events occur:

1. p1 retrieves `idx` value of 0 from queue and then loses control of the CPU before it has a chance to get a random number and store it
2. p2 retrieves `idx` value of 1 from queue
3. p2 gets the first random number, 9,  and stores `data[1] = 9`
4. p1 gets the second random number, 11, and stores `data[0] = 11`

Already we see the results are not duplicated. The only way to ensure duplication would be to serialize all the code between `idx = queue.get()` and `data[idx] = torch.rand(1)` with a `multiprocessing.Semaphore` so that you guarantee any process that retrieves the Nth index is also retrieving the Nth random number from the seeded sequence. Assuming that you are doing "real" work in your actual code and that the results for a given index only depends on the random number used, then this should be doable without any performance impact. You would allocate a semaphore and use the *initializer* and *initargs* arguments to initialize each pool process with the semaphore and you would place the previously described *critical section* within a `with semaphore:` block:

```py
def init_pool_processes(sem):
    global semaphore

    semaphore = sem

def collect(...):
    ...
    while True:
        with semaphore:
            idx = queue.get()
            if idx is None:
                break
             random_number = torch.rand(1)
        # do real work in the following function call:
        data[idx] = some_function_of(random_number)
    ...

    collect_pool = ProcessPoolExecutor(num_collect_procs,
                                       mp_context=ctx,
                                       initializer=init_pool_processes,
                                       initargs=(multprocessing.Semaphore(),)
                                       )
```

Let's repeat the same two scenarios where each process has its own random number generator:

First run:

1. p1 retrieves `idx` value of 0 from queue
2. p1 gets the first random number, 9, and assigns `data[0] = 9`
3. p2 retrieves `idx` value of 1 from queue
4. p2 gets the first random number, 9, and stores `data[1] = 9`

Second run:

1. p1 retrieves `idx` value of 0 from queue and then loses control of the CPU before it has a chance to get a random number and store it
2. p2 retrieves `idx` value of 1 from queue
3. p2 gets the first random number, 9, and stores `data[1] = 9`
4. p1 gets the second random number, 11, and stores `data[0] = 11`

The only possible way that I can see of ensuring duplicate runs is if you split all the possible indices into two groups and you have two input queues. You pass to `p1` one of the queues to which you put half the indices and you pass to `p2` the other input queue to which you have written the remaining indices. That ensures that the random number used for any index does not vary from run to run, i.e. the Nth index retrieved by a given process will be using the Nth random number. **In this case you should seed each process differently to avoid computing the same results for different indices.**

**Update**

Your logic seems to be overly complicated with pools, which have their own internal queues, processes, threads, queues, etc. Frankly, I am having some difficulty in following what you are doing. But the following is my idea of achieving repeatability of results. Here I assume that the random number generator is not sharable across processes and I use an implementation for which I know that to be the case. Therefore, I create N processes and each one seeds its own random number generator uniquely to minimize the probability of multiple processes generating the same random number (which wouldn't be fatal if that were to happen, I assume). A shared array initialized to zeros is created and passed to each process. But each process has its own input queue from which it is retrieving indices and I write 1/N of the indices to each queue so that each will repeatedly generate the i<sup>th</sup> random number in the sequence its seeded random number generator will create when it retrieves the i<sup>th</sup> index that has been passed to it:

```py
import random
from multiprocessing import Queue, Process, Array

N_PROCESSES = 4
INDICES_PER_PROCESS = 5

def worker(seed, queue, array):
    # Use a different seed for each process:
    random.seed(seed)

    while True:
        idx = queue.get()
        if idx is None:
            break
        array[idx] = random.randint(0, 100_000_000)

def run_trial():
    array = Array('i', INDICES_PER_PROCESS * N_PROCESSES, lock=False)
    processes = []

    idx = 0
    for seed in range(N_PROCESSES):
        queue = Queue()
        p = Process(target=worker, args=(seed, queue, array))
        p.start()
        processes.append(p)
        for _ in range(INDICES_PER_PROCESS):
            queue.put(idx)
            idx += 1
        queue.put(None)

    for p in processes:
        p.join()

    return array



def run_trials():
    array1 = run_trial()
    l1 = list(array1) # For easy comparison

    array2 = run_trial()
    l2 = list(array2)

    print('l1 =', l1)
    print('l2 =', l2)
    assert l1 == l2

if __name__ == '__main__':
    run_trials()
```

Prints:

```None
l1 = [51706749, 56448162, 5433721, 34751217, 68622131, 18034063, 76397250, 8470054, 34234785, 15826780, 7590196, 12292302, 11391326, 48460313, 22694018, 31939071, 79542916, 73045210, 17505051, 49654541]
l2 = [51706749, 56448162, 5433721, 34751217, 68622131, 18034063, 76397250, 8470054, 34234785, 15826780, 7590196, 12292302, 11391326, 48460313, 22694018, 31939071, 79542916, 73045210, 17505051, 49654541]
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply and sorry for my late response.  I can fix the seed using both thread and proc pools initializer, and this guarantees that each proc and thread generates the same sequence of random number. As you said, though, the order each process writes into the data is random and depends on the queue. I tried using a semaphore as in your code but it doesn't work. In the MWE I can split the indices, but in my real problem I can't really do anything like that. I guess I can't really have deterministic behavior, right? (I have edited my question.)

Comment: I have appended an update to my answer that may (or may not) be of some use to you. I am hoping you can adapt the general approach to what you are actually doing.

Comment: Thanks! I use a Pool because it seems the easiest way to launch processes. Most of the examples I find only suggest to use it because it's easier. I see the logic of your approach and I will try to make it work with my code. Thanks again for your help!

Answer (score 0):

According to the logic of work, you need to run data collection and testing of the corresponding model in one process. And then they were already divided into two streams of training and testing, since they are constantly waiting for each other. That is, you need one process pool, each with two threads. Then you can achieve predictable results.

Comment: I need to use multiple processes. Training and testing is done on multiple dataset, and to speed things up I do it in parallel. In my MWE I just assign a random number to a tensor, but imagine that each of this number is read from a file. If I read files in parallel my program is so much faster.